# Socket.io drag and drop functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, sockets

How can i drag and drop an image over the canvas in real time with sockets,i have already tried but remain in vain so help me if anyone could please.i am working on a app with node and i am successful in drop operation but in dragging again it doesn't work.

Comment: Sockets and canvas are two completely different things. Canvas is used to draw stuff in the view, sockets to communicate both ways between the server and the client. So, no idea what you are trying to achieve here. Voting to close as unclear what you're asking

Comment: I am typing to emit the coordinates of the dragged image through sockets and then emit them to other

Comment: And i am doing it on a div

Comment: Still no clue about what you're trying to do. `I am typing to emit`, what does this mean? Typing to emit? `the coordinates of the dragged image` the coordinates relative to what? The DOM? So what is a canvas doing here? `through sockets`, at least this is easy : `socket.emit('coordinates', data)`. `and then emit them to other` Emit the coordinates to other what? Dude, take some time to write a proper and clear question, because this is just gibberish.

Comment: Ok well my mistake all i wanted to say is that i am making something like a functionality which drag tool from tool list on the dom element and while doing this i want to emit the position of dragged tool to other client on the server in real time.